# Where can I find documentation on built in read only list columns for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, read-only

I know for a fact that ID is a built in read only column. I think most SP admins and developers know this. Someone is trying to convince me otherwise.

All I could find on MSDN was the following:

"in SharePoint lists, you can view the built in ID column as a permanent, unchangeable primary key; and this is the value that drives the relationship"

[List Relationships in SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798514.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [SPBuiltInFieldId class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspx) for the names and Ids of built-in fields.